# Server-Client not connecting

Tags: c, sockets

I am new to socket programming in C. I am stuck over here. Below are the server and the client .c program files. problem is they are not getting connected.Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is the client.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(void)
{
int host_socket =0,add_length,bufflen;
struct sockaddr_in host_addr;
struct hostent *h;
char recvbuffer[1024];

host_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
host_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
host_addr.sin_port = 5000;
host_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

if(bind(host_socket,(struct sockaddr*)&host_addr,sizeof(host_addr))<0)
{
    printf("\n Could not connecct to Server !!");
    return 1;
}

recvfrom(host_socket,recvbuffer,(sizeof(recvbuffer)-1),0,(struct     sockaddr*)&host_addr,&add_length);
fputs(recvbuffer,stdout);
return 0;
    }
```

this is server.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


int main(void)
{
int serv_socket =0;
char sendbuffer[1024];
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

serv_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = 5000;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

bind(serv_socket,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));

listen(serv_socket,10);

while(1)
{

accept(serv_socket,(struct sockaddr*)NULL,NULL);
strcpy(sendbuffer,"your ip is not traced try again !!");

sendto(serv_socket,sendbuffer,strlen(sendbuffer),0,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));

close(serv_socket);
sleep(1);
}
return 0;
    }
```

Comment: accept and bind in server, connect in client

Comment: The major problem is that you're using UDP sockets, which are by design *connectionless*. The second problem is that you barely check for errors. And a third problem is that your "client" program looks like an UDP "server" program, but only for one datagram.

Comment: `sendto(serv_socket,sendbuffer,strlen(sendbuffer),0,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));` You are sending to `serversocket`, the return value of `accept` is the new socket, after client connects, you should use this socket value to send data to.

Comment: The client program should not bind to a local address (well, it doesn't *need* to anyway). And it should *send* data. The server program binds to a local interface (or any interface) and calls `recvfrom` in a loop. When it has received a datagram, it can send back data to the "client" using the address information filled in by the `recvfrom` call. I suggest you read some manual/reference pages about the `recvfrom` and `sendto` functions.

Comment: Besides, your port number isn't actually 5000. You forgot that the port numbers must be in *network byte order* (use the `htons` function). When you fix everything else it should work for just these two programs, as both make the same mistake.

Comment: @codepad: Read [Beej's Guide to network programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)

Comment: @codepad: I am bit of confused about your code.Like your `client` code seems simillar to server.And UDP is connection less So only `bind` is enough in `server` code. Look here for simple code http://www.abc.se/~m6695/udp.html

Comment: UDP doesn't need accept() or listen() because UDP doesn't mean a connection.

Comment: Also see some simple examples.  http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~almeroth/classes/W01.176B/hw2/examples/udp-client.c  http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~almeroth/classes/W01.176B/hw2/examples/udp-server.c

Comment: @someuser You might want to link to the folder containing the examples instead of directly to a single example.